# What do 'the one' and 'it' refer to in the passage?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Do they refer to ***know-how and information*** and ***a structure*** respectively? Or, just an abstract, general concept?

> Know-how and information are distinct, but they are also intimately
> connected. The ability of a system to pack know-how depends largely on
> the fluidity with which it can use information to reconstruct the
> dynamic networks it needs to accumulate that know-how. A seed is a
> perfect example of this. It is a package containing both the know-how
> and the information needed to create a plant, such as a tree. The
> development of a tree is nothing other than the majestic unpacking of
> know-how facilitated by genetic information. A seed unpacking into a
> tree unpacks the know-how needed to perform photosynthesis, to build
> the structures that will transport nutrients and water from the ground
> to the leaves, and to defend itself against pests. A seed unpacking
> into a tree is an example of know-how and information being unpacked
> into a structure that is more complex than ***the one that begot it***
> — the tree has the ability to perform functions that were absent in
> the seed.

[Why Information Grows: The Evolution of Order, from Atoms to Economies](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=0984DgAAQBAJ&pg=PT127&lpg=PT127&dq=Know-how%20and%20information%20are%20distinct,%20but%20they%20are%20also%20intimately%20connected.%20The%20ability%20of%20a%20system%20to%20pack%20know-how%20depends%20largely%20on%20the%20fluidity%20with%20which%20it%20can%20use%20information%20to%20reconstruct%20the%20dynamic%20networks%20it%20needs%20to%20accumulate%20that%20know-how.%20A%20seed%20is%20a%20perfect%20example%20of%20this.%20It%20is%20a%20package%20containing%20both%20the%20know-how%20and%20the%20information%20needed%20to%20create%20a%20plant,%20such%20as%20a%20tree.&source=bl&ots=G-NWxr_bJz&sig=ACfU3U2rurSRvcP3SybCZ3dQ1LJMLVWHzA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwja6LLfuMb9AhWE62EKHYLeCXMQ6AF6BAgEEAM#v=onepage&q=Know-how%20and%20information%20are%20distinct%2C%20but%20they%20are%20also%20intimately%20connected.%20The%20ability%20of%20a%20system%20to%20pack%20know-how%20depends%20largely%20on%20the%20fluidity%20with%20which%20it%20can%20use%20information%20to%20reconstruct%20the%20dynamic%20networks%20it%20needs%20to%20accumulate%20that%20know-how.%20A%20seed%20is%20a%20perfect%20example%20of%20this.%20It%20is%20a%20package%20containing%20both%20the%20know-how%20and%20the%20information%20needed%20to%20create%20a%20plant%2C%20such%20as%20a%20tree.&f=false)

Comment: ***the one*** and ***it*** both refer to ***a structure*** - but they're obviously *different instances* of structures, since the former *created* the latter.

Answer (score 2):

"Know-how" and "information" are normally mass nouns, so "the one" should not refer to them. Instead, "the structure" serves as the antecedent of both "the one" and "it". However, "the one" must refer to a different structure, since it "begot" the other one. The sentence could perhaps be more clearly written as:

> . . . unpacked into a structure that is more complex than the **earlier structure** that begot it . . .

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two ways to read it. In the first way, the noun phrase "the one" refers to a seed, and the object "it" refers to a tree. In the second (more abstract) way, the noun phrase "the one" refers to a base structure, and the object "it" refers to a derived structure.

The author is explaining how we often use information as a basis for creating something. This happens in nature. A tree can emerge from the genetic information of a seed.